# Multiple SQL Joins error in W3Schools Tryit Editor

Tags: mysql

I hope that you can help me with this slightly thorny problem. I am using the W3Schools SQL tutorial and in the process of doing this, I am inventing 'real-world' queries to try and get some experience at this stuff. Using their database, I am trying to find out who ordered what using the following:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, p.ProductName
FROM Customers c inner join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderDetails od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID;
```

This keeps returning the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'c.customerid = o.customerid join orderdetails od on od.orderid = o.orderid join products p on p.productid = od.productid'.

After lots of fiddling about, and having a more experienced colleague look at my query, we can't find what's wrong with what I have written.

Please could you provide me with some help/guidance.

Comment: I have tried the query and work fine in w3cschoold tutorial .. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/  (copy and paste the code and try)

Comment: scaisEdge, Thanks for coming back to me so quickly. I tried it again and it still didn't work, but, as it worked for you, I was inspired to try it in a different browser, and it worked. So, in Firefox, this didn't work. In Chrome, it did. Odd!

Comment: Sometimes different browser work in different way ..is  normal use different browser for developement and  testing .. I use FF with firebugs etensions for testing and debuggin .. and Opera for presentation (very fast) occassionaly a use chrome just for resideual compatibilty ..

Comment: Working fine on google chrome.But getting error in firefox .

Comment: I _think_ I know a bit about what's causing the error: it's something to do with ads. If I click on the AdChoices link in Chrome and then come back to the same page, errors start cropping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query is not wrong and not giving any error i'm ruining this query on w3school http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

open this link and paste the query.

```
    SELECT c.CustomerName, p.ProductName
    FROM Customers c inner join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderDetails od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to their documentation here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Section - "JOIN Three Tables"

If I re-write your code like below then it works fine in W3School's try it editor.

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, p.ProductName
FROM ( ( ( Customers c inner join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID )
    inner JOIN OrderDetails od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID )
    inner JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID );
```